# How to add references to a model to use it twice with different name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I have two models Game and Team. I want every game to have exactly two teams a **hometeam** and an **awayteam**. I also want to have access to **@game.hometeam** and **@game.awayteam**.

**games**

```
 create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "admin_id"
    t.integer "stadium_id"
    t.integer "hometeam_id"
    t.integer "awayteam_id"
  end
```

**teams**

```
create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "name"
   t.integer "capacity"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

**and my controllers for Game , Team is empty**

```
has_one :hometeam , :class_name => 'Team' 
has_one :awayteam , :class_name => 'Team'
```

Comment: switch `has_one` to `belongs_to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, according to [Rails API :has_one](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) definition:

> Specifies a one-to-one association with another class. This method
>   should only be used if the other class contains the foreign key. If
>   the current class contains the foreign key, then you should use
>   belongs_to instead. See also
>   ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods's overview on when to use
>   has_one and when to use belongs_to.

so your Game definition should use [:belongs_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) to specify this type of relation.

Secondly, to specify the attribute to be used in the relation you must set the `:foreign_key` option.

> By default this is
>   guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix. So a
>   class that defines a `belongs_to :person` association will use
>   “person_id” as the default `:foreign_key`. Similarly, `belongs_to :favorite_person, class_name: "Person"` will use a foreign key of
>   “favorite_person_id”.

So according to the docs you could do:

```
class Game
  belongs_to :hometeam, foreing_key: 'hometeam_id', class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :awayteam, foreign_key: 'awayteam_id', class_name: 'Team'
end
```

or the implied form:

```
class Game
  belongs_to :hometeam, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :awayteam, class_name: 'Team'
end
```

Then each Team could have many games:

```
class Team
  has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'hometeam_id'
  has_many :away_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'awayteam_id'
end
```

Comment: ok. that works but i have i conflict in some other part .If i want to use has_one the only change is that i have to move hometeam_id and awayteam_id to teams?

Comment: I recommend checking the [Active Record Associations Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I understand , how can i do the same with has_many? Sorry for the spam but i want to figure it out. Thanks for your time i appreciate the help.

Comment: @MarkosTzetzis i updated the answer to include the `has_many` relationship